# How to change activity on bottom navigation button click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I want to use bottom navigation bar in my existing android app but the problem is all screen are activity ,is it possible to load activity without hiding the bottom navigation bar.

**example:**
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Your loooooong scrolling content here. -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my base activity,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomBar bottomBar;
        bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                if (tabId == R.id.matching) {
                    Log.i("matching","matching inside "+tabId);
                    Intent in=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }else if (tabId == R.id.watchlist) {
                    Log.i("matching","watchlist inside "+tabId);
                    Intent in=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main2Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        NestedScrollView dynamicContent = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollingContent);
        View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
        dynamicContent.addView(wizard);
```

**Main3Activity**

```
public class Main3Activity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        NestedScrollView dynamicContent = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollingContent);
        View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main3, null);
        dynamicContent.addView(wizard);


    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bottom.bottomnavigation">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you provide screenshots?

Comment: Besides your question, Main3Activity shouldn't even work because findViewById can't find views if you don't have a content view

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have solved this problem in following way:

1.Create one **BaseActivity** with bottom nav bar.

```
 package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RadioGroup radioGroup1;
RadioButton deals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);


    radioGroup1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    deals = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.deals);
    radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            Intent in;
            Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 bro" + checkedId);
            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.matching:
                    Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 matching" +  checkedId);
                    in=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MatchingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    break;
                case R.id.watchList:
                    Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 watchlistAdapter" + checkedId);

                    in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WatchlistActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

                    break;
                case R.id.rates:
                    Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 rate" + checkedId);

                    in = new Intent(getBaseContext(),RatesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    break;
                case R.id.listing:
                    Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 listing" + checkedId);
                    in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    break;
                case R.id.deals:
                    Log.i("matching", "matching inside1 deals" + checkedId);
                    in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DealsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

BaseActivity layout named **base_activity.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bottonNavBar"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom">


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Matching"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_matching"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                android:id="@+id/matching"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_watchlist"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                android:id="@+id/watchList"
                android:text="Watchlist"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/rates"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_rates"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                android:text="Rates"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_deals"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                android:id="@+id/deals"
                android:text="Deals"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_listing"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                android:id="@+id/listing"
                android:text="Listing"/>


        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicContent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </LinearLayout>
```

2.extend BaseActivity in all the activity that you want to open on bottom nav click and also need to inflate the activity layouts
For example, I have created five sample activity.

**i] MatchingActivity.**

```
  package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
              //extends our custom BaseActivity
    public class MatchingActivity extends BaseActivity {
        LinearLayout dynamicContent,bottonNavBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_matching);


                       //dynamically include the  current activity      layout into  baseActivity layout.now all the view of baseactivity is   accessible in current activity.
            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.dynamicContent);
            bottonNavBar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottonNavBar);
            View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_matching, null);
            dynamicContent.addView(wizard);


              //get the reference of RadioGroup.

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.matching);

                 // Change the corresponding icon and text color on nav button click.

            rb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.ic_matching_clicked, 0,0);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        }

    }
```

**ii]WatchlistActivity**

```
 package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;

    public class WatchlistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        LinearLayout dynamicContent,bottonNavBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_watchlist1);

            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicContent);
            bottonNavBar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottonNavBar);
            View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_watchlist1, null);
            dynamicContent.addView(wizard);

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.watchList);
            rb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.favourite_heart_selected, 0,0);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        }
    }
```

**iii]RatesActivity**

```
  package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;

    public class RatesActivity extends BaseActivity {
        LinearLayout dynamicContent,bottonNavBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // setContentView(R.layout.activity_rates);

            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicContent);
            bottonNavBar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottonNavBar);
            View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_rates, null);
            dynamicContent.addView(wizard);

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rates);
            rb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.ic_rate_clicked, 0,0);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        }
    }
```

**iv] ListingActivity**

```
 package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;

    public class ListingActivity extends BaseActivity {
        LinearLayout dynamicContent,bottonNavBar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             //setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);



            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicContent);
            bottonNavBar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottonNavBar);
            View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_listing, null);
            dynamicContent.addView(wizard);

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.listing);
            rb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.ic_listing_clicked, 0,0);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        }
    }
```

**v] DealsActivity**

```
 package com.example.apple.bottomnavbarwithactivity;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;

    public class DealsActivity extends BaseActivity {

        LinearLayout dynamicContent,bottonNavBar;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_deals);
            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicContent);
            bottonNavBar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottonNavBar);
            View wizard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_deals, null);
            dynamicContent.addView(wizard);

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.deals);
            rb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0,R.drawable.ic_deals_clicked, 0,0);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));



        }
    }
```

**Note:** make sure that you handle **back press** properly.I have not written any code for **back press**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm implementing this code, what I can't understand is how to avoid activities to be re-created? I mean, I lose activity state and it is created from scratch again

Comment: you can save activity state checkout this post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

Answer (score 5):

With `Activity`, you have to declare and init that `BottomBar` each time you load that `activity`.

With your problem, my answer is **NO**.

Btw, you can use [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) which helps you solve this pretty good.

Time to learn something new, bro.

**EDIT**

You bring `Fragment` inside only **1** Activity. And let `BottomBar` inside `Activity` while all others view and data set inside `Fragment`.

Just try it!

Comment: my app has  five main screen and all are activity ,now it is very difficult and time consuming to change these activities into fragment is there any way so that i can achieve bottom navigation view with my existing activities.

Comment: Did you research `Fragment`? I think it won't be too hard and not much work with only 5 screens :D. Both `Activity` and `Fragment` not different much.
You should change for later maintance.

Comment: What about SettingsActivity? Can I place it in the bottomnavbar?